# Iron::new()::http() intercepts stdin

Tags: rust, iron

I'am trying to implement educational client-server application using Rust and Iron. I've encountered the behaviour that I can't understand. Here is the code:

```
fn main() {
    Iron::new(hello_world).http("localhost:3000").unwrap();

    let mut input = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut input)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    println!("You entered: {}", &input)
}


fn hello_world(_: &mut Request) -> IronResult<Response> {
    Ok(Response::with((status::Ok, "Hello World!")))
}
```

When I run it and try to enter something from the keyboard, the line **You entered: Some text** is not appearing.

But after I changed this line:

```
Iron::new(hello_world).http("localhost:3000").unwrap();
```

With this:

```
let listener = Iron::new(hello_world).http("localhost:3000").unwrap();
```

I got string **You entered: Some text** on my console. So it seems to work. But now I have warning about unused variable. This behaviour is confusing.

Can anyone explain why this actually happens?

Comment: Because when you drop the listener it will block till the server dies, when you move it to a variable, it'll block when the variable is dropped (i.e. scope end) -- you can prefix the variable with `_` (like `_listener`) to silence unused warnings.

Comment: Thanks you. And thanks for nice hack with `_listener`. I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first version of your code, the first line will block waiting for incoming connections. This is because of the following:

1. `Iron::new(hello_world).http("localhost:3000").unwrap()` produces an object of type `Listening`, which will start listening to http requests **in a separate thread**.
2. The `Listening` struct implements the `Drop` trait, i.e. any objects of type `Listening` will run a `drop` function when they fall out of scope. Said drop function will **join the listening thread, blocking further execution of your program**.
3. By not assigning the `Listening` object to a variable, it falls out of scope immediately. This means that **the `drop` function is run right after the object's creation**.

## Alternative explanation in code

The first version of your program:

```
fn main() {
    Iron::new(hello_world).http("localhost:3000").unwrap();
    // The listening thread is joined here, so the program blocks
    // The instructions below will never be executed

    let mut input = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut input)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    println!("You entered: {}", &input)
}
```

The results of introducing a variable:

```
fn main() {
    let listener = Iron::new(hello_world).http("localhost:3000").unwrap();

    let mut input = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut input)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    println!("You entered: {}", &input)

    // The listening thread is joined here, so the program blocks
    // As you can see, the program will not exit
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation! Do this pattern have a name in Rust?

Comment: I mean, is it a common practice to do so?

Comment: This is a common pattern, not only in Rust. C++ has destructors, for instance, which are also executed when an object falls out of scope. You can read more about `Drop` in the [Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/book/first-edition/drop.html)

Comment: The pattern is very useful in languages without garbage collection, like Rust. You can use it to ensure any memory allocated by your object is freed when the object is destroyed (otherwise you would have to do that manually, with a chance of forgetting to do it and introducing a memory leak). This pattern is called [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) in C++, and I have seen the same name used in Rust context (see, for instance, [this resource](http://rustbyexample.com/scope/raii.html))